# postgis package in "apt install postgis postgresql-14-postgis-3 postgresql-14-postgis-3-scripts" makes the database change version from 14 to 15

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgis, apt

If I attempt to install this, I receive my wished *postgresql 14.8* version:

```bash
sudo apt install gnupg2 wget ca-certificates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim

echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install gnupg2
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt -y install postgresql-14 postgresql-client-14
sudo apt -y install postgresql-14-postgis-3 postgresql-14-postgis-3-scripts
```

But I discover that an utilitarian, `shp2pgsql`, is missing. It is part of a package named `postgis`.

If I correct the last line of my install script with:

```bash
sudo apt -y install postgis postgresql-14-postgis-3 postgresql-14-postgis-3-scripts
```

It comes, but the postgresql database is now: 15.3

If I change the:

```bash
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

changing its:

```bash
"deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main"
```

by:

```bash
"deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg 14"
```

(main -> 14)
it doesn't find `postgresql-14` or `postgresql-client-14` and ends the installation quickly.

What am I in front of, and how do I find my way facing such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the PostgreSQL 15:

```
sudo apt-get remove  libboost-serialization1.71.0 libgmpxx4ldbl libprotobuf-c1 libsfcgal1 postgis-doc postgresql-15 postgresql-15-postgis-3 postgresql-15-postgis-3-scripts postgresql-client-15 postgresql-postgis
```

or the packages that were the previous installation when you ran the command to install PostGIS and then run the following:

```
sudo apt install postgis postgresql-14-postgis-3-scripts
```